# Count number of lines in an in-built function, extract range of lines by specifying numbers

Tags: r, function, count, tail, head

Lets say I have an in built function whose code is very lengthy, so I want to count the number of lines in the function and display just part of code by providing the range of numbers to some function.

To see how many lines are there in a function, I used `tail()` function, which will display numbers in front of each line

```
  tail(XYZ_Function)
```

I tried using `head()` and `tail()` combination, i.e. lets say I want from lines 145 to 150 of a function, so I did

```
  tail(head(XYZ_Function,n=150),n=5)
```

Is there any function available in R besides using `head()` and `tail()` in combination where I can just provide object name, and two numbers to extract the lines from that object.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for this one, but you could write youre own function:

```
code_block <- function(x, y, z) { # x = your function, y = lower limit, z = upper limit
  dat <- data.frame(head(x, n = z))
  dat[which(as.numeric(rownames(dat)) >= y  & as.numeric(rownames(dat)) <= z), ]
}


code_block(summary.lm, 12, 20)



> code_block(summary.lm, 10, 20)

10         w <- z$weights                                                  
11         if (is.null(w)) {                                               
12             rss <- sum(r^2)                                             
13         }                                                               
14         else {                                                          
15             rss <- sum(w * r^2)                                         
16             r <- sqrt(w) * r                                            
17         }                                                               
18         resvar <- rss/rdf                                               
19         ans <- z[c("call", "terms", if (!is.null(z$weights)) "weights")]
20         class(ans) <- "summary.lm"
```

Comment: I was also thinking of writing my own function for this purpose, as there does not seem to be any in built function available. I tried your function, it works really well. Could you please also put a statement inside your function to display the count of number of lines or else I will edit No problem. Because I won't now what should be my range you know, I mean I should not put a number for upper limit greater than the numebr of lines. Thank you, for now it works!!

Comment: @Sowmya S. Manian sry, not sure what you are looking for!